# Skype URI doesn't work on new version Skype in iOS

Tags: ios, skype

I have developed one application which use Skype URI for dial the tel number.

```
NSString* stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"skype:%@", strTel];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringURL]];
```

But the Skype URI doesn't work.

I remembered it worked before.

Now, it only opened Skype, and nothing happens (It used to dial the tel number before).

I checked the [skype document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/skypeuris/skypeuriapireference?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), but seems nothing change.

Did I miss anything?

Please help me to solve this issue.

PS: I already added the key `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in Info.plist file for skype

Answer (score 0):

Firsly check skype is in your device or not. You can use below code for Skype and check real device.

```
 BOOL skypeInstalled = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"skype:"]];
if(skypeInstalled){

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"skype:echo123?call"]];

} else {

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/skype/id304878510?mt=8"]];
}
```

Or Use as this

```
 NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"skype:USER_NAME?call"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: urlString]];
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Skype URI for user name is OK, but tel number is still failed.

Comment: Seems like it's he bug in Skype app. it only works when the Skype app is quit. And if the the Skype app is in background then it doesn't perform any action and just opened up.